# Paste option disabled in Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 8.1

Tags: 18.04

My laptop has Windows 8.1 Professional and Ubuntu 18.04 installed in it. I'm unable to paste any files to the common drives. When I right click, the Paste option is disabled. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> also doesn't help. Anybody please help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue before and i solved it , just simple steps:

**1.** Open your Windows , Go to `Control Panel` and search for `Battery`
**2.** Click on `Power Options`

[image]

**3.** From right hand side ,  click on `Choose what closing the lid does`

[image]

**4.** Click on `Change settings that are currently unavailable`

[image]

**5.** uncheck this option `Turn on fast startup (recommended)`

**6.** Click `Save changes` and Restart your PC.

[image]

**Congrats** , Now you can copy and paste from Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes it worked! Finally I got it resolved after a long trouble. Thank you very much @Ahmed Emad! :)